# filtering const data in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

i have a vue app with ad group of data.

```
const data = [
 {
   name: 'value1',
   id: 'id1',
   supervisor: true,
 },
 {
  name: 'value2'
  id: 'id2',
  supervisor: false,
 }
]
```

but i just need to display data for supervisor = true only.

i'd tried to filter it with belows code but it did not work.

```
const test = data.filter(data => data.supervisor = true);
console.log(test);
```

can somenone share any reference for me to refer for this filtering function as i new in vue js. or anyone can share their knowledge. because actually i have the data from api which need to be display with some sort of condition.

i have tried using `url/api/items?supervisor=true` and then i was inform that the API did no support for that kind of way so i need to create a filter function in javascript from data that retrieve from APIs. i'm using above `const data =[{...,...}]` in this question for it easier to understand.

Comment: `data => data.supervisor > true` will be false so you'll end up with nothing - you really only need to `const test = data.filter(data => data.supervisor);` - by the way, this question has nothing to do with vuejs - it's a javascript question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const test = data.filter(data => data.supervisor === true);
```

Full working example, since your `data` was also missing a comma, so the *not working* part can be from there:

```
const data = [
 {
   name: 'value1',
   id: 'id1',
   supervisor: true,
 },
 {
  name: 'value2',
  id: 'id2',
  supervisor: false,
 }
];
const test = data.filter(data => data.supervisor === true);
console.log(test);
```

Comment: `=== true` is redundant in data where supervisor is only true or false

Comment: *where supervisor is only true or false* from your affirmation is the key part. We don't know here whether `supervisor` is **only** true or false. It can be also `true`ish, while OP explicitly said he only wants data where supervisor is `true`.

Comment: sure - but the example data shows only true or false, and the OP made no suggestion that it could be otherwise - you decided it could be any value at all, and that's not wrong. But I read the question and go by the information given and make no assumptions :p

Comment: if you go by that logic and **really** want to make no assumptions and provide the simplest way to solve the problem for the current data, you can: `test = data[0]`

Answer (score 1):

You should use `const test = data.filter(data => data.supervisor);` instead of `> true`